# how to join two tables:one table has 'text' key, the other has 'number' key

Tags: sql

there are two tables that i try to merge together using ID

table 1 is like:

| ID | feature |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blue |
| 2 | red |
| 3 | black |

table 2 has extra text in front of ID, looks like:

| ID | location |
| --- | --- |
| num1 | az |
| num2 | ca |
| num3 | ny |

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON 'num' + table1.ID = table2.ID
```

Concatenate the literal 'num' and the ID of table 1 to match with the ID of table 2.

Some SQL implementations use `||` to concatenate instead of `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

`JOIN table2 ON SUBSTRING(table1.ID, 4, 100) = cast(table2.ID as varchar(8))`

Answer (score 0):

Just substring the Table2 id so you get only the numeric part, then you can join that calculated id to the Table1 id